# Kivy ScrollView (with Gridview) Suffering Performance Issues

Tags: python, kivy

I have a GridView inside of a ScrollView. I am trying to create and display approximately ~12,000 items in the GridView (which clearly will not display appropriately on screen), but the number of items could feasible be ~40,000. Currently ~18 seconds are spent constructing all of the items (Labels), and any resizing of the window results in another significant delay.

How can I speed up the construction and rendering of the items? I don't know how to do paging or delayed, on-demand loading on a ScrollView.

Comment: Some code would be nice. There is a limitation on how many times you can add widgets in a single clock's tick so that your ui won't freeze.(depends on hardware, I think) However if you use just a `for`, it'll freeze until it's done. Maybe try to use threading, if Clock is not enough. Btw, of course the window resizing will delay it, because kivy then recalculates size and pos of each present widget and if you keep pushing widgets when it's recalculating, I'm afraid it'll wait until the recalcucating is done(i.e. when you have hundreds of widgets, then a lot).

Comment: Just adding all the items probably isn't a good idea. I'd look at RecycleView, a new and relatively good automatic solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

How can you imagine a user scrolling through 40000 labels? You should rethink your app design.

Consider adding a text input, and based on the given string, fetch filtered data from the database you have.

Comment: 1. It's a sovereign desktop application, not an app.
2. The 40,000 labels would correspond to 8,000 lines.
3. There is no database to query: the data is the contents of a log file.
4. There is filter regex field, as well as record type filters, but if no filters are applied (as is default), there will be many lines.

Comment: @FluxIX 1) It doesn't matter in this case. 2) Still too much. 3) ; 4) Then show only top 50 (or other small number) newest logs when there is no filter string. Even if the labels would be created under a second, you still shouldn't display thousands of them. Maybe *somebody somewhere* does it in their program, but it doesn't mean its good, and its so easy to fix in kivy.

Comment: Just to add; if you display, let's say top 50 newest logs, and a user wants to see top 100, then just put a button at the end "show 50 more", which would add those 50 more on demand.